# Conditional expectation of a set of Gaussian variables

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, conditional-expectation

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to compute the conditional expectation of every element in a Gaussian random vector ?

Specifically:

For a pair of Gaussian random variables  $[x,y]$, the conditional expectation is $E[x\mid y] = \mu_x - \Sigma_{x,y} \Sigma_{y,y}^{-1}[y -\mu_y]$ where $\Sigma$ is (co)variance and $\mu$ is mean.

Now given a $n$-dimensional Gaussian random vector $[x_1 \ldots x_n]$, I want to compute $E[x_i \mid \bigcup x_j, \forall j\neq i]$, that is for each component $i$ I want its expected value given every other component.

One straight forward way would be to use the conditional expectation formula for each $i$ - which would involve $n$ inversions of $n-1 \times n-1$ covariance matrices.

However, it appears to me that there is a lot of redundancy in this approach. Is a more efficient way to compute this without having to do this $n-1\times n-1$ inversion per-element ?

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote "For a pair of Gaussian random vectors", but this actually works only if the whole tuple $[x,y]$ including all components of $x$ and all components of $y$ together is _jointly_ Gaussian, which  means it is so distributed that every linear combination of the components is Gaussian (where the coefficients in the linear combination are constant, i.e. not random). ${}\qquad{}$